# Traduction de "superposed dot"

Tags: anglais, mathématiques

Je sais qu'en français on peut dire quelque chose comme :

> Une autre notation usuelle (de la dérivée temporelle, à savoir de la dérivée par rapport au temps) est celle attribuée à Newton, qui consiste à **pointer** la variable dérivée.

Je me demande comment l'on interprète la locution **superposed dot** ; par exemple pour la phrase suivante :

> A superposed dot denotes a total time derivative.

serait-elle ?

> Un point superposé indique une dérivée temporelle totale.
>
> Un dot superposé indique une dérivée temporelle totale.
>
> Un sous-point indique une dérivée temporelle totale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La traduction habituelle est simplement *point au-dessus* :

> - *A superposed dot denotes a total time derivative.*
> - Un point placé au-dessus (de la variable) indique une dérivée temporelle.

Le résultat se lit <nom-variable>-<point>, par exemple `ẋ` se lit « **x point** ».

Pour la dérivée seconde, on rajoute un deuxième point, `ẍ` et on lit « **x point point** » et ainsi de suite; dérivée troisième, <sub>[image]</sub> : « **x point point point** »...

---

Quelques références (c'est moi qui souligne) :

https://automaths.blog/2017/09/03/newton-contre-leibniz-la-lutte-de-linfiniment-petit/

> Ce procédé est appelé méthode des fluxions ; le temps et la vitesse sont des quantités fluentes. Newton notait alors les petits changements de vitesse ou de temps en ajoutant un **point au-dessus** de ces quantités.

https://lewebpedagogique.com/the-green-lantern-of-conakry/tag/calcul-infinitesimal/

> Ne s’intéressant qu’au point de vue physique de la chose, il étudie l’accélération en mécanique et la relation entre position et vitesse, et décide que la dérivée sera annotée avec **un point au-dessus** des lettres.

https://lehollandaisvolant.net/?mode=links&d=2016/05/06

> Note :La notation « x' » n’était pas utilisée par Newton. Newton utilisait la notation « **x point** » (**un point au dessus** du x, ou du y : je ne sais pas la faire au clavier).
>   Pour la notation « dy/dx », ou « x' » (x prime), il faut attendre Leibniz.

http://public.iutenligne.net/mecanique/mecanique-du-solide/charbonnieras/mecanique/113_vecteur_vitesse.html

> On a également l'habitude de noter les dérivées par rapport au temps par un **point au dessus** de la grandeur : [image]

Comment: J'ai vu aussi _suscrit_ probablement aussi en typographie...

Comment: Et pour la dérivée seconde on a 'x point point', 'x point point point' pour la troisième, etc. On ne dit pas 'x [n] points'. Ce qui est un peu étonnant d'ailleurs.

Comment: Avec un clavier ‘bépo’ :  AltGR + Maj. + i + [azAZ]

Answer (score -1):

En mathématiques les écrivains utilisent « **en chef** » pour dire « placé sur le symbole (ni à gauche en superscript gauche ni à droite en superscript droit ou autrement dit en exposant) mais bien au milieu. Je ne trouve cependant aucune référence de dictionnaire pour confirmer cela.

On peut donc dire « un point en chef » ou peut être, dans le cas des dérivées, puisqu'elles sont représentées par de très gros points, « un pois en chef ».

Il me semble que l'on puisse dire aussi, peut être que de façon moins spécifique,  des choses comme « point superposé sur le symbole ».

Je n'ai jamais trouvé « dot » ; je crois que c'est seulement de l'anglais; ça n'est pas utilisé en français standard, on dit « point » ou « pois » et il ne semble pas que les scientifiques aient introduit ce terme (il n'y en a pas besoin, « pois » fait l'affaire).

Comment: Un *pois en chef* !!! Seriously ???

Comment: @jlliagre C'est si on accepte d'appeler un gros point un pois, mais il n'y a pas de doute sur « point en chef » ; je l'ai trouvé plusieurs fois dans des sources variées.

Comment: *Point en chef* existe bien en typographie, mais l'expression est inconnue de la plupart des non typographes. Le problème principal de cette suggestion, c'est qu'Il faut accepter d'appeler un point un pois et c'est, il me semble, largement plus extravagant que la prononciation de *village* par Charles Trenet...

Comment: @jlliagre Non, il n'y a rien d'extravagant : qu'est-ce qu'une puce au jeux de puce ? qu'est-ce que l'on appelle une puce dans le texte ? ce n'est ni plus ni moins qu'un gros point. C'est du même ordre de relativité.

Comment: Tu aurais pu tenter *puce en chef*, ce qui aurait mis une touche d'humour à ta réponse, mais proposer *pois* sans indiquer qu'il s'agit d'une pure invention de ta part est irresponsable. D'autre part, écrire *En mathématiques les écrivains utilisent* est pour le moins maladroit, ce sont les mathématiciens qui écrivent ainsi, pas les écrivains. Ta méconnaissance du français t'aura fait confondre *writer* et *écrivain*.